# .Net Core add reference to project under different solution

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Using .net Core 2.0 here

I have a visual studio .net solution where I have created a .net core 2.0 web mvc application.

This application now requires an reference from a class library (written in .net core 2.0 as well) which is under different solution and directory.

When I try to add reference (adding as a project) of my class library in my web it doesn't allows me to add and throws error 
" The reference is invalid or not supported"

Looking for inputs to resolve this error.

Comment: Do you try to add a reference (library only) or do you try to add the entire project?

Comment: I add entire project as just adding library reference does not work.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5954)